# Update Excel Sheet (in Classic ASP/Vbscript)

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I tried to search for a code that would update a Excel (XLS) file in Classic-ASP but I cannot get it to work.

here is what I have:

```
<!--#include file="../adovbs.inc"-->
<%
' Open and Update and then Close The XLS File
Dim objConn
set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim FLConnect
Dim strSQLexcel

' Create the connection string.
    FLConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("TEST.xls") & "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No'"

' Create the SQL statement.
    strSQLexcel= "UPDATE [Sheet1$A1:A1] SET F1='TestValue1'"

set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'Set objConn = New ADODB.Connection

' Create and open the Connection object.
    objConn.Open FLConnect

' Execute the insert statement.
    objConn.Execute strSQLexcel

' Close and destroy the Connection object.
    objConn.Close

%>
```

But I keep getting an error saying: " The connection cannot be used to perform this operation. It is either closed or invalid in this context. "

Thank you so much...

Comment: Try it with the missing ; - ...xls") & "Ext.. - ...xls") & ";Ext..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your connection string is not right.

You have:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 Data Source=" 
& Server.MapPath("TEST.xls") & "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No'"
```

You are missing a semi-colon after 4.0 and before Extended

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" 
& Server.MapPath("TEST.xls") & ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No'"
```

See http://connectionstrings.com

Comment: I changed it to: FLConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("TEST.xls") & "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No'" 
 but still the same error! :-(

Comment: Thanks for the website I will have a look at it now.

Answer (score 1):

This connection string worked best for me:-

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myExcel.xlsm;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES';
```