# refreshing page after reading an excel file generates an error

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

i am reading an excel file using this code i found over the net:

```
<% Option Explicit %>
<html>
<body>
<%
Dim objConn, objRS, strSQL
Dim x, curValue
Dim valuesArray()

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM A1:A200"

Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)}; IMEX=1; HDR=NO; "&_
    "Excel 8.0; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("myExcel.xls") & "; "

Set objRS=objConn.Execute(strSQL)

Response.Write("<table border=""1"">")
Response.Write("<tr>")

For x=0 To objRS.Fields.Count-1
   Response.Write("<th>" & objRS.Fields(x).Name & "</th>")
Next

Response.Write("</tr>")

Do Until objRS.EOF

    Response.Write("<tr>")

    For x=0 To objRS.Fields.Count-1
        curValue = objRS.Fields(x).Value
        If IsNull(curValue) Then
            curValue="N/A"
        End If
        curValue = CStr(curValue)
        valuesArray(x) = curValue
        Response.Write("<td>" & valuesArray(x) & "</td>")
    Next
    Response.Write("</tr>")
    objRS.MoveNext

Loop

objRS.Close
Response.Write("</table>")
objConn.Close

Set objRS=Nothing
Set objConn=Nothing
%>
</body>
</html>
```

upon first visit of the page the excel file is read properly. but if i refresh the page i get this error:

> Provider error '80004005'
>
> Unspecified error

would you happen to know what is causing this and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time this error is because you are refreshing too fast; if you were to wait like 10 sec or so it should not give you that error. Though ASP/ADO applications support multi-user access, an Excel spreadsheet does not. Therefore, this method of querying and updating information does not support multi-user concurrent access.

see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q195951/

Comment: most of the time this error is because you are refreshing too fast if you where to wait like 10 sec or so it should not give you that error. Though ASP/ADO applications support multi-user access, an Excel spreadsheet does not. Therefore, this method of querying and updating information does not support multi-user concurrent access

Comment: would you happen to know of any other way to read excel files without using ADOs? i tried timing the refresh time and its around 1 minute which is simply too long

Comment: @user571099 give this a try http://planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=8413&lngWId=4 and also my question that I posted here sometime ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621015/update-excel-sheet-in-classic-asp-vbscript Hope it helps, good luck :)

Comment: @user571099 just so everyone knows and/or if someone has the same problem how did you solve it ? was it the planet-source-code link or the link to my question on stackoverflow or was it something totaly different ? Thx.

Comment: it was your microsoft link that made me realize i cannot use adodb. i switched to oledb. please look at this [link](http://chiranzeev.blogspot.com/2011/09/classic-asp-read-excel-with.html)