# Save ASP classic form into a specific column in excel

Tags: asp-classic, vb6, vbscript, excel, vba

I'd to know if it's possible to have my asp classic form saved into a excel file in a column  after submit?

Thank you all.

Comment: Sure, you can have a web page written in ASP 3.0 that saves form data to an Excel spread sheet.  Why not?

Comment: I already have a page written and have my form ready in place. and i do have my excel file already, but how would you have the form saved into the existing excel file.

Answer (score 1):

use the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB Driver to access the excel sheet like so:

```
dim conn : set conn = server.createObject("ADODB.Connection")
dim rs : set rs = server.createObject("adodb.recordset")
dim sql

conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" &_
          "myExcelFile.xls;" &_
          "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"""
```

then you yould use just sql to insert your data...

the possible connectionstrings for excel are listed [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel)

Answer (score 0):

THE BELOW CODE IS TO INSERT INTO AN EXISTING EXCEL FILE. THIS IS WHAT YOU NEED.

```
<%
    Option Explicit 

    ' OPEN DATABASE 
    dim objConn,strConnection,objRS,strQuery

'Set objConn = New ADODB.Connection 
    set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
    objConn.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("TEST.xls") & "; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;" 
    objConn.Open strConnection 

'Set objRS = New ADODB.Recordset
    set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 
    set objRS.ActiveConnection = objConn 

' This is to Select A1:A1 and open the recordset     
    strQuery = "SELECT * FROM A1:A1" 
    objRS.Open strQuery 

' This is to insert into A1:A1 a value that says: testttest     
    strQuery = "insert into [A1:A1] values('testttest')" 

' Close and destroy the Connection object. 
    objConn.Execute strQuery 
    objConn.Close
    Set objRS=Nothing
    Set objConn=Nothing
%>
```

TO UPDATE A SPECIFIC COLUMN

You can do this: See here: http://bytes.com/topic/asp-classic/answers/620074-update-existing-excel-file-using-asp-urgent
and also here: [Update Excel Sheet (in Classic ASP/Vbscript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621015/update-excel-sheet-in-classic-asp-vbscript)